# Onclick select then off

Tags: javascript

I am using basic code to highlight the text within a text field when the user clicks in it:

```
<input type="text" id="search_for" name="searchTerm" onclick="this.select()">
```

Which is great, but you only have the choice to delete, meaning you can't actually click in the middle of the selected text to add something in the middle of words/characters already in there.

Scenarios... if a user does a search for "red car", they should be able to click in the box, its hightlighted, so hit delete and search for "blue car". Or, they might want to click in the input and change their search to "big red car".

Is it possible to click then unset the highlight by clicking again? Or what other method could I use?

Or should I select the field on page load, then click to un-select? Is that even possible?

I've searched extensively for this but no luck as yet.

Comment: Why have the highlight then? The default behavior is to insert wherever the cursor is positioned.

Comment: What do you want to do and what do you mean by highlight? I am not sure if you really want to select it or just highlight the textfield with for example a different background-color when it's focused.

Comment: @DRP96 Highlight the text not the actual element - I highlight it as its then easier to delete it, updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep track of the number of clicks in the input and basically toggle `select()` vs `focus()`.  It may not be exactly what you are referring to, but it is something you *could do*.

***[See working jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/nXf9S/)***

### HTML:

```
<input type="text" 
       id="search_for" 
       name="searchTerm" 
       onclick="searchForClick(this);" 
       value="text text text text" />​
```

### JavaScript:

```
searchForClickCount = 0;

function searchForClick(el) {

    if (searchForClickCount === 0) {
        el.select();
        searchForClickCount++;
    } else if (searchForClickCount >= 0) {
        el.focus();
        searchForClickCount = 0;
    }

}​
```

Comment: Brilliant! That's exactly it! Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Also, for good measure, just to make sure it keeps track of clicks in the correct order, you could wrap the whole if statement in another if statement checking to make sure the field actually contained a value.